# Which is the additional stroke added to 末 and to 未? significance?

Tags: characters

I'm curious whether the shorter stroke or longer stroke are the extra strokes added to 木 to form the characters 未 and 末? And do these strokes have a semantic significance? I learned that 本 has the extra stroke at the bottom for the meaning of root. I'm expecting that 未 and 末 have a comparable explanation that might help me remember them, as I'm continually getting these two mixed up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

末 is logographically comparable to 本. The top stroke indicates the top branches of a tree, the end of the tree. Hence the meaning "end".

However, 未 is unrelated to both characters above, it is just a representation of a tree. It is one of the twelve earthly branches, and as such a character that once had some original meaning that is now lost to us; it has been abstracted to mean "not yet".

Comment: 《说文解字》：……未……六月……木老於未。象木重枝葉也。……  I assume there's some relationship between 未 and 木.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it was one of the earthly branches. Also, I was poking around a bit more and found this description on Uncle Hanzi's etymology for 未: "Primitive pictograph 未. A tree with new branches (buds) 未 indicating something that has yet to arrive. Meaning future." Does this conflict with your comment about 未 being unrelated?

Comment: Or, perhaps better to say, that the longer stroke _emphasizes_ the upper branches, hence terminus.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[鐵](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)・197.1
[合集10070](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=10070&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>商
甲
[image]
[燕](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)165
[合集37986](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=37986&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
利簋
[集成4131](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4131&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
秦律雜抄
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

「未」depicts a flourishing tree (tree with more branches or longer branches than「木」), indicating the meaning *fragrance* (i.e. when trees/plants are in full bloom). The current shape is derived from a variant with two more branches drawn, and these extra branches became straightened out into one stroke over time.

This word that「未」represented is now written as「味」(e.g. 味道, *smell*), while the senses *not yet* (e.g. 未來, *future*) and *earthly branches* (地支) are both [phonetic loans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Rebus_(phonetic_loan)_characters).

---

<kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
金
[image]
蔡侯紐鐘
[集成218](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=218&jgwfl=)</kbd>

<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image]
[木部・末](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=63)
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd><kbd>今
楷
[image]</kbd>

「末」depicts a tree with a mark at the upper end, indicating the meaning *upper extremity > end*. The mark grew in length over time.